# How to find the average of data samples at random intervals in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, numpy

I have temperature data stored in a csv file when plotted looks like the below image. How do I find the average during each interval when the temperature goes above 12. The result should be the T1, T2 ,T3 which should be the average temperature during the interval when its value is above 12.
Could you please suggest how to achieve this in python?
[image]

Highlighted the areas approximately over which I need to calculate the average:
[image]

Please find below sample data:

```
R3,R4
1,11
2,11
3,11
4,11
5,11
6,15.05938512
7,15.12975992
8,15.05850141
18,15.1677708
19,15.00921862
20,15.00686921
21,15.01168888
22,11
23,11
24,11
25,11
26,11
27,15.05938512
28,15.12975992
29,15.05850141
30,15.00328706
31,15.12622611
32,15.01479819
33,15.17778891
34,15.01411488
35,9
36,9
37,9
38,9
39,16.16042435
40,16.00091253
41,16.00419677
42,16.15381827
43,16.0471766
44,16.03725301
45,16.13925003
46,16.00072279
47,11
48,1
```

Comment: Please provide data in text format.

Answer (score 1):

In pandas, an idea would be to group the data based on the condition `T > 12` and use mean as agg func. Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
# a dummy df:
df = pd.DataFrame({'T': [11, 13, 13, 10, 14]})
# set the condition
m = df['T'] > 12
# define groups
grouper = (~m).cumsum().where(m)
# ...looks like
# 0    NaN
# 1    1.0
# 2    1.0
# 3    NaN
# 4    2.0
# Name: T, dtype: float64

# now we can easily calculate the mean for each group:
grp_mean = df.groupby(grouper)['T'].mean()
# T
# 1.0    13
# 2.0    14
# Name: T, dtype: int64
```

Note: if you have noisy data (T jumps up and down), it might be clever to apply a filter first (savgol, median etc. - whatever is appropriate) so you don't end up with groups caused by the noise.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a good pattern for this - here's a clunky bit of code that does what you want, though.

In general, use .shift() to find transition points, and use groupby with transform to get your means.

```
#if you had a csv with Dates and Temps, do this
#tempsDF = pd.read_csv("temps.csv", columns=["Date","Temp"])  
#tempsDF.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
#Using fake data since I don't have your csv
tempsDF = pd.DataFrame({'Temp': [0,13,14,13,8,7,5,0,14,16,16,0,0,0]})
#This is a bit clunky - I bet there's a more elegant way to do it
tempsDF["CumulativeFlag"] = 0
tempsDF.loc[tempsDF["Temp"]>12, "CumulativeFlag"]=1
tempsDF.loc[tempsDF["CumulativeFlag"] > tempsDF["CumulativeFlag"].shift(), "HighTempGroup"] = list(range(1,len(tempsDF.loc[tempsDF["CumulativeFlag"] > tempsDF["CumulativeFlag"].shift()])+1))
tempsDF["HighTempGroup"].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
tempsDF.loc[tempsDF["Temp"]<=12, "HighTempGroup"]= None
tempsDF["HighTempMean"] = tempsDF.groupby("HighTempGroup").transform(np.mean)["Temp"]
```

[image]

[image]